# Binding to Attributes when Application Starts

Tags: ember.js

When my application first starts up and the application view loads, I attempt to bind to boolean attributes in order to conditionally set a CSS class.  The boolean attributes are initialized properly but the class does not get set.  The binding seems to work fine after the startup.  Here is a JSFiddle that demonstrates the [issue](http://jsfiddle.net/jimpresley63/uWJWh/).  Any ideas why this fails the first-time it runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received an answer from the ember.js team on GitHub.

Here's the response from Kristofor Selden...

> Your template outputs 2 class attributes, and when jQuery brings it into DOM it removes the >  latter, it does not merge them. After that the binding updates the attribute in DOM.
>    If you want a static class and a bound class you need to put the static class in the 
>    bindAttr helper with
>    {{bindAttr class=":something isB:redbg:greenbg"}}
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/krisselden/uWJWh/9/

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the `redbg` into the conditions as well ?

http://jsfiddle.net/uWJWh/4/

edit:
Updated jsfiddle to use `toggleProperty`

http://jsfiddle.net/uWJWh/5/

Comment: +1, Note there is a `toggleProperty()` function to do this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the toggleProperty() tip.  The problem appears to be when a class attribute exists and then the bindAttr is adding a class to it.  The first time it doesn't add it.  I updated the last version of the fiddle to demonstrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/uWJWh/7/