# Emberjs bindAttr inside of #each

Tags: ember.js

Code for view is

```
Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(html), // html is in string
        content: function() {
            return [
            { Title: "Dashboard", ID: "dashboard" },
            { Title: "Invoices", ID: "invoices" },
            { Title: "Expenses", ID: "expenses" },
            { Title: "People", ID: "people" },
            { Title: "Reports", ID: "reports" },
            { Title: "Settings", ID: "settings" }
        ]},
        iconClass: function(link){
          return "icon icon-" + link.ID
        }
    });
```

Template (show above as "html") looks like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each link in view.content}}
    <li>
        <a>
            <span class="icon" {{bindAttr class="view.iconClass(link)"}}></span>
            <span class="title">{{link.Title}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This renders

```
<span class="icon" data-bindattr-2="2"></span>
```

So additional class attribute is not rendered. Am I doing something wrong with scope or?

**NOTE:**

I changed my code to show what I want to do.

Comment: perhaps you can try something like this: <span {{bindAttr class="iconClass :icon"}}></span> If it works, I can put it as an answer

Comment: I had a similar problem.  Check out this [thread][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876317/binding-to-attributes-when-application-starts/12083813#12083813

Comment: WHat I am trying to do is to put dynamic class name regarding to "link" var from my each loop. Something like this: 

class="icon icon-"+link.ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

According to the new question, you'll have to use an `Ember.CollectionView`:

```
App.FooCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        iconClass: function() {
             return "icon-dashboard icon " + this.get('content.ID');
        }.property('content.ID')
    })
});
```

As you can see, each `itemViewClass` has a property `iconClass` which depends on its `content.id`.

Now you'll have to add the collection view in the template of the view `FooView`:

```
<ul>
    {{#collection App.FooCollectionView contentBinding="view.content"}}
    <li>
        <a>
            <span {{bindAttr class="view.iconClass"}}>foo</span>
            <span class="title">{{view.content.Title}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/collection}}
</ul>
```

Here we are using the `{{collection}}` Handlebars helper, and we bind the content of the `FooView` to the `FooCollectionView`.

It will automatically create an `itemViewClass` instance for each object in the CollectionView.content, set the its to the associated object, and add it to the view.

I suggest you to read the [Ember.CollectionView documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html).

And [you could try this solution in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeVpZ/1/).

Comment: I changed my answer code to show you what I am trying to achieve. Is this doable?

Answer (score 3):

For others who are having the problem with bindAttr resulting in something like:

`data-bindattr-1="1"`

make sure you are using

`{{bindAttr src="myvariable"}}` 
instead of `{{bindAttr src="{{myvariable}}"}}`

Might save you some time searching for the answer, this was what caused my code not to work.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to do this is to add a computed property to your model. In the example below I needed a specialized style atribute.

Model ----

```
App.Photo = Em.Object.extend(
  objectId: null
  url: ""
  style: (-> 
    "background-image:url('" + @get("url") + "')"
  ).property("url")
)
```

Template -----

```
{{#each item in App.photoController}}
<div {{bindAttr style="item.style"}}></div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: It feels strange putting a view-esque property on a Model object, but as long as it's used as a View Model I guess that makes sense.